# I have a problem. When I save my data in localStorage it loses reduce. And shows me the data inside like 0,23,20,11 Instead of a uniform result

Tags: javascript

I have a problem.
When I save my data in localStorage it loses reduce.
And shows me the data inside like 0,23,20,11
Instead of a uniform result.

When I add the products everything is updated superbly.
It makes me reduce and puts me the data evenly.
But that I disconnect from the user and reconnect.
It shows me the data like 0,23,20,11
(According to the products I added at the beginning).
I have a problem that it does not save me the reduce and breaks them down for me.

```
/*Class*/
const LoginBtn = document.querySelector('.login__btn');
const inputLoginUsername = document.querySelector('.login__input--user');
const inputLoginpin = document.querySelector('.login__input--pin');
const main_body = document.querySelector('.main-body');
const userUX = document.querySelector('.user');
const items = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');
const proteinInfo = document.querySelector('.protein');

let currentAccount;

/*Profiles*/

const profile1 = {
  username: 'Daniel',
  pin: 1234,
  protein: [0],
};

/*Attracting users*/
const profiles = [profile1];

/*Foods*/
const foods = new Map([
  ['קוטג', 23],
  ['ביצה', 11],
  ['יוגורט Pro', 20],
  ['טונה', 23],
]);

/*Login Btn*/
LoginBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  currentAccount = profiles.find(
    acc => acc.username === inputLoginUsername.value
  ); // find user

  if (currentAccount?.pin === Number(inputLoginpin.value)) {
    main_body.style.opacity = 100;
    userUX.textContent = `${currentAccount.username}`;
    inputLoginpin.value = inputLoginUsername.value = '';

    proteinInfo.textContent = localStorage.getItem('SaveProtein');
  }
});

foods.forEach(function (value, index, arr) {
  const html = `<li class=""> <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary add-item" data-protein="${value}">הוסף</button>
    <strong>${index}</strong> כמות חלבון ${(proteinValue = value)}</li><hr>`;
  items.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
});

document.querySelectorAll('.add-item').forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    currentAccount.protein.push(e.target.getAttribute('data-protein'));
    protein = currentAccount.protein.reduce((acc, val) => acc + Number(val), 0);
    proteinInfo.textContent = protein;
    localStorage.setItem('SaveProtein', currentAccount.protein);
  });
});
```

**Before I log out of the user**
[image]

**After I reconnect to the user.
This is what the problem is for me**
[image]

Comment: The result of the reduce is in `protein`, not `currentAccount.protein`.

Comment: Look at my code.
I select currentAccount.protin so that it stores the data in the profile that the user logged in to and not with everyone.
Everything works.

Again just that does not make me reduce.
I have attached pictures for illustration. @Barmar

Comment: `currentAccount.protein` is an array. Storing an array in local storage converts it to a string, which puts `,` between all the array elements. So `0,23,20,11` comes from the protein array `[0, 23, 20, 11]`.

Comment: Then when the page loads you do `proteinInfo.textContent = localStorage.getItem('SaveProtein');` which shows that comma-separated string.

Comment: But now it keeps me the same result in all my profiles @Barmar

Comment: You only have one localStorage variable. How is it supposed to keep different profiles?

Comment: Why don't you save the entire `profiles` array in localStorage? Use `JSON.stringify()` when saving, and `JSON.parse()` when restoring.